# Git - push to a remote-tracking branch in the remote repository

Tags: git, branch, push

When simply doing `git push` to a remote repository, its `master` branch gets updated. This is undesirable in the case of non-bare repositories, and the warning message displayed by recent Git versions makes that clear.

I'd like to be able to push to a remote repository, and have one of its *remote tracking* branches be updated. Later, when I log in to the remote machine and run commands, I can choose to merge that remote tracking branch into `master`.

How can I do that? Or is there a better way to push changes to a non-bare repository?

Comment: I want to setup something similar. The intention is to promote changes as early as possible to the remote tracking branch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do:

```
git push master:some-remote-branch
```

for example:

```
git push master:alex/master
```

(Although it is still not recommended to push to non-bare repository.)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should just set up a separate bare repository, ie. one without a working copy. Then you could just log in to the remote machine and clone this remote repository, and fetch/pull whenever you need it.