# "git push" doing the same as "git fetch" from the remote

Tags: git, push, fetch

My question is the same as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2144866/git-push-to-a-remote-tracking-branch-in-the-remote-repository), but the answer is not clear to me.
I have two git repos A and B in sync (corresponding to the two machines I work on). When I start working in B, I would normally do `git fetch A` (assuming the remote A in B points to repo A).
But I want instead being able to push from A to the remote branch A inside B whenever I work in A. I want to be sure that it is safe, because of the warnings concerning pushing to a non-bare repo. My settings (in file A/.git/config) would be:

```
[remote "B"]
fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/B/*
push =  +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/A/*
url = ssh://<machine_B>/home/project/B
```

With this setting, do I get *exactly* the same result with this two commands? :

- in A: `git push B`
- in B: `git fetch A`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the exact answer to my question on [kerneltrap mail archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20130516000629/http://kerneltrap.org/mailarchive/git/2007/3/19/241732), by one of the main git developers. So yes, both commands are equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

If you do `git push B` in A, you already update refs in B (only the ones you actually pushed), so that a subsequent `git fetch A` in B is not be required to update the specific updated refs.

Comment: Yes, but when switching to machine B, can I choose between the two options and be sure that they will have the exact same result (and that pushing will be totally safe)?