# What would be the opposite of "git fetch"?

Tags: git, git-fetch

If I do git fetch from repo `A` to `B`, the master branch in `B` doesn't change - changes only `remotes/origin/master`, and `git status` reminds me of it.

But now I want to do the opposite - update `B` from `A`, something like pushing from `A:master` to `B:remotes/origin/master`. The reason for this is that this update happens over ssh, and `A` machine has public-key auth to `B` machine - but not vice versa.

How can I do this?

Comment: very related [“git push” doing the same as “git fetch” from the remote](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4239064/11343)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`git fetch A`, run from `B`, will store all current branches of `A` in `refs/remotes/A`. As you can do pretty much everything with [refspecs](http://git-scm.com/book/ch9-5.html), it's possible to do the same for a `git push`, but run from `A` and targeting `B`.

A refspec has two parts, separated by a semicolon. In the first part you select what you want to push. Here you want all current branches, so this is `refs/heads/*`.

Second part is where you'll store them on the remote; here you want to store them under `remotes/A/*`, so this is `refs/remotes/A/*`.

Put it together, to push all local branches to corresponding remote branches with this command:

```
git push --force B refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/A/*
```